# Google Maps Api: infowindow vs infobubble?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, infobubble

I'm trying to create a map with multiple markers using google maps api v3 javascript. I've read many tutorials and I really confused about infowindows/infobubbles. Is it the same thing or are they different, and how? It seems to me that they are two different things cause there's a different object created in each case.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var infobubble = new google.maps.InfoBubble();
```

Anybody knows more information about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- A [google.maps.InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) is a built in object in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)
- A [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) is a "third party" replacement for an InfoWindow, it has similar functionality but more flexibility in some ways.

Answer (score 2):

Infobubble is a third party library that extends Google Maps functionality. (And that's why [it's found in google maps utility library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/))

It offers additional styling properties (sometimes styling infowindows is a bitch to deal with) but, in turn, it's not supported by google and it might happen that a future google maps release might break it.

Answer (score 2):

I think difference between us are just because infowindows is a basic tooltip with Google map skin (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=FR) and infoBubble are more editable, with tabs, and personal skin (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/)